# how to single the list of list in java

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, flatmap

I have a code here that getting the List of List in java. But my problem now is the result in my server was repeatable...

**Example**

```
[2012-01-04, 3 , 2012-02-04, 4, 2012-05-04, 3][2012-01-04, 3 , 2012-02-04, 4, 2012-05-04, 3][2012-01-04, 3 , 2012-02-04, 4, 2012-05-04, 3]
```

The value number of value inside my array is the same 3 group of arrays appearing.
This is my code. please help me.

```
SortedSet<String> uniqueSet = new TreeSet<String>(arrlist);
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  // List<String> flat = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
  ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(String date : uniqueSet) { 
    int counts = Collections.frequency(arrlist, date);
     Logger.debug("date: "+ date + " counts: " +counts);
      singleList.add(date);
      singleList.add(Integer.toString(counts));
      listOLists.add(singleList);

    }
    Logger.debug("Sample List: " + listOLists);
    return listOLists;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you create the inner list only once before the loop. You then change that single list instance in every loop run with inserting the *same* list instance again and again to the outer list.

Changing that single list instance will change all occurrences of it in the outer list.

So simply move the line

```
ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

inside the loop. This will then create a new inner list at each loop run.

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying and adding the same list. Probably you want to declare it inside the loop.

```
SortedSet<String> uniqueSet = new TreeSet<String>(arrlist);
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  // List<String> flat = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
  for(String date : uniqueSet) { 
    int counts = Collections.frequency(arrlist, date);
     Logger.debug("date: "+ date + " counts: " +counts);
      ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
      singleList.add(date);
      singleList.add(Integer.toString(counts));
      listOLists.add(singleList);

    }
    Logger.debug("Sample List: " + listOLists);
    return listOLists;
}
```

Comment: how can i add some for loop?